# MySQL filter for multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

Assuming i have following table

```
STUDENTS
--------
StudentID   Course
1           1
1           2
1           3
2           1
2           2
3           1
3           3
```

Also, I have a certain set of important courses

```
IMPORTANT COURSE
----------------
Course
1
2
5
8
```

How can I find out which students take exclusively important courses? (Student 2 in this case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you group by the student you can count the number of courses that are not in the `important courses` table. That count should be `0`

```
select studentid
from students s
left join `important courses` c on c.course = s.course
group by studentid
having sum(c.course is null) = 0
```